# Flickr API .NET: Creative Commons License Search returns "All Rights Reserved" images?

Tags: .net, flickr

I'm using the official .NET wrapper for Flickr's API. When I do a search for photos of freely usable pictures as shown in the following code snippet, I get back 3 photos whose licenses print out a "All Rights Reserved":

```
        Flickr flickr = new Flickr(Settings.Default.fli_key);
        PhotoSearchOptions options = new PhotoSearchOptions();
        options.Tags = "start";
        options.IsCommons = true;
        options.Licenses.Add(LicenseType.UnitedStatesGovernmentWork);
        options.Licenses.Add(LicenseType.NoKnownCopyrightRestrictions);
        PhotoCollection photos = flickr.PhotosSearch(options);
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var photo in photos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + ":" + photo.License);
            i++;
        }
```

Console:

```
0:AllRightsReserved
1:AllRightsReserved
2:AllRightsReserved
```

Questions:

- What am I doing wrong?
- If I'm not doing anything wrong, what is the problem here? Is the .NET library broken?
- What can I do to fix the issue? I really only want pictures of the requested licenses.

I appreciate your help :-)

Comment: Noone has worked with the .NET Flickr API so far? :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was having the same issue with PHP until I removed the 'is_commons' parameter from my call and searched only by license id (license=2). Now all my responses are the requested license type. Perhaps is_commons trumps license or they conflict? Dunno, I just got started with the API. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try that out next week and will report if this fixed the issue.

Comment: It also works with the .NET API, if you set all your license types right and just igore the isCommons option, it works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: how do you set the license types in the .net api? The PhotoSearchOptions.Licenses property cannot be set directly.

Comment: In case anyoen else is wondering, here is the syntax:   options.Licenses.Add(LicenseType.AttributionCC);